# Breakpoint Settings VS2015 C++ does not Support breakpoint conditions

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm currently trying to set a condition for a program I am debugging and it asks me "Action or Condition". I choose condition then I type in:

```
var == 111
```

In the field and leave the middle field as "is true"

But when I press enter. It gives me the error

> C++ does not support breakpoint conditions.

I googled this already and one person mentioned that I have to install the redistributable pack. I check and it is already installed with the latest version.

Please help

Comment: What's the type of variable `var`?

Comment: Are you running the debug or release version

Comment: That's not about the languages C or C++, but your toolchain.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/10/06/new-breakpoint-configuration-experience-in-visual-studio-2015/ gives some hints that might help.

Comment: The variable type is an int @martinZhai

Comment: Could you show a screenshot with your code snap and breakpoint detail? Because everything is fine at my side. I'm using VS2015 too.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i use this

```
if (Var==111)
{
    _asm{int 3}
}
```

To force a breakpoint 
I know, it is a bit dirty code..

Answer (score 0):

Hi C++ support breakpoint conditions .

first press f9 for enable the breakpoint.

right click on that breakpoint and click on condition give yours condition as    var=111.

click on ok.

this may work .

follow the below link.
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/10/06/new-breakpoint- configuration-experience-in-visual-studio-2015/

or you can use if statement .